# C++ char variable 2 words

Tags: c++, string, char

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main(){
  char name[20];
  cin>>name;         // when I input "This is" 
  cout<<name<<endl;  // output was "This" 
}
```

How to do that when I input "This is" , output too will  be  "This is" , not only "This" ?

Comment: Never use `operator>>` directly into a char array, you open yourself up to buffer overflows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
cin.get( name, 20 );
```

or

```
cin.getline(name, 20);
```

Depending on whether you want the new line character in your string.

EDIT:

If you want to further simplify your code you could use a string instead of a char array, you wouldn't have to worry about the user exceeding your buffer size then ie.

```
string name;
getline(cin, name);
cout << name << endl;
```

EDIT 2:

As David Heffernan also pointed out in a comment I should explain why it's not working for you as expected.  The extraction operator (`operator >>`) ends when a whitespace character -- a space in your case -- is reached.  The operator also terminates when a null-character or the end of file is reached.

Comment: I think your answer would be improved if as well as offering good advice you answered the question as to why only one word was being read. Then I can delete my answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I added an explanation.  Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, I've now deleted my answer as I believe it now offers nothing beyond what yours does.